# Doubly Linked List inserting at node in the beginning

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am learning Java Doubly Linked List.

I am trying to build a method that can insert in the beginning of list.

```
 public ListDeque()     
   {
      header = new DNode( 0, null, null );
      trailer = new DNode( 0, null, null );
      header.setNext(trailer); 
      trailer.setPrev(header);  
      size = 0;
   }


public void insertFirst( int e )
    {
        DNode newNode = new DNode(e, header, null);
        
        
        if(header != null)
        {
            header.prev = newNode;
        }
        header = newNode;
        if(trailer == null)
        {
            trailer = newNode;
        }
        size++;
        
        System.out.println("Adding " + e );
    }
```

I am not sure if this is correct and how could I check if I am on the right track?

Also, this is my main method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ListDeque q = new ListDeque();
            q.insertFirst(120);
            q.insertFirst(15);
            q.printDeque();
            q.isEmpty();
}
```

but it give me errors after executing first two method.

> Adding 120
> Adding 15
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "doublyLinkedListwHeaderAndTrailer.DNode.getElement()" because "p" is null
> at doublyLinkedListwHeaderAndTrailer.ListDeque.printDeque(ListDeque.java:27)
> at doublyLinkedListwHeaderAndTrailer.ListMain.main(ListMain.java:9)

which I believe it is related to this method. But I am not sure why it is incorrect.

```
public void printDeque( )
    {
    for ( DNode p = header.getNext(); p != trailer; p = p.getNext() )
        System.out.print( p.getElement() + " " );
    System.out.println();
    }


public class DNode {
  protected int element;    
  protected DNode next, prev;   

  /** Constructor that creates a node with given fields */
  public DNode(int e, DNode p, DNode n) {
    element = e;
    prev = p;
    next = n;
  }

public int getElement() { return element; }

 
  public DNode getPrev() { return prev; }

 
  public DNode getNext() { return next; }

  
  public void setElement(int newElem) { element = newElem; }

 
  public void setPrev(DNode newPrev) { prev = newPrev; }

  public void setNext(DNode newNext) { next = newNext; }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The constructor looks like you're creating _sentinel_ head and tail elements that aren't real elements of the list, they just mark the boundaries. But then within `insertFirst` you have code that anticipates them being null and tries to deal with this, and also reassigns them. Those two approaches are inconsistent. You should think more carefully about exactly how you're approaching this implementation.

Comment: can you please also post the DNode constructor code? what are the three parameters for in your DNode constructor?

Comment: Hello, I just did. I am still trying to change it but I am not sure where I am making mistakes. thank you.